# shapely polygon_.buffer(0) "loses" half my bowtie

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapely

I've seen online that buffer(0) should "fix" bowties. Shapely finds the intersection point of the bowtie, but only keeps the top-right portion. Looking for a workaround, I tried reversing the order of my points. Surprisingly (to me), the same top-right portion of the bowtie was still the one kept. I don't understand. Any help appreciated.

I would like to retain the entire bowtie as two triangles (ore one six-sided polygon--either would be useful). Looking for a workaround for this "problem."

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

bowtie_plot = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]

bowties = [
        Polygon(bowtie_plot),
        Polygon(bowtie_plot[::-1])
        ]

cleaned = [
        bowties[0].buffer(0),
        bowties[1].buffer(0)
        ]

print('cleaned[0] exterior = {}'.format(list(cleaned[0].exterior.coords)))
# cleaned[0] exterior = [(0.0, 0.0), (-1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0)]

print('cleaned[1] exterior = {}'.format(list(cleaned[1].exterior.coords)))
# cleaned[1] exterior = [(0.0, 0.0), (-1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0)]

# ADDITIONAL INFORMATION BELOW
# here's what shapely *can* do with intersecting lines:
# a star shape made of five intersecting lines and five points

from math import sin, cos, pi

star = Polygon(
        [(cos(x*pi*4/5), sin(x*pi*4/5)) for x in range(5)]
        ).buffer(0)

# after buffering, becomes a star shape made out of ten lines and ten points
# shapely found all intersections and corrected the polygon.
print('list exterior = {}'.format(list(star.exterior.coords)))
```

After thinking about it, I can understand *why* a bowtie is treated differently than a star, but I'm interested in finding a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried closing the polygon. I don't know shapely but I looked at one of their Polygon examples and it appears that they close the polygon (have the same first and last point).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting self-intersecting polygon only returned one polygon in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110632/splitting-self-intersecting-polygon-only-returned-one-polygon-in-shapely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bowtie is not a valid shapely [Polygon](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons).  Read that documentation, and the documentation for [LinearRing](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#LinearRing) (just above the `Polygon` documentation).  In particular, note the examples of valid and invalid `LinearRing`s.

If you create the bowtie like this:

```
In [46]: bt = [(1,0), (0,1), (0,0), (-1,0), (0, -1), (0,0)]

In [47]: poly = Polygon(bt)
```

then `buffer(0)` returns a [MultiPolygon](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#MultiPolygon):

```
In [48]: poly.buffer(0)
Out[48]: <shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon at 0x4a40050>
```

Answer (score 0):

`buffer(0)` does not always produce a MultiPolygon:

```
from shapely.wkt import loads

bt = loads('POLYGON ((0 0, 2 2, 2 0, 0 2, 0 0))')<br>
bt.buffer(0).wkt 

produces 'POLYGON ((1 1, 2 2, 2 0, 1 1))'
```